# echo command turns whitespace into new line

Tags: echo

How to list files—whose filename has whitespace in it—and put them all into a text file. Unfortunately, the command below turns all whitespaces into new lines, e.g. `filename aba.txt` will be turned into:

```
filename
aba.txt
```

I'd like to output:

```
filename aba.txt
```

The command I use is:

```sh
$ for f in `ls -v *.txt`; do echo "$f"; done >> Output.txt
```

I thought that by surrounding `$f` with quotes, no new line would be created every time there's a space in the filename. Obviously not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe to `xargs` with an explicit delimiter (to '\n'):

```sh
ls -1 *.txt | xargs -n 1 --delimiter '\n' echo > output.txt
```

Note #1: `ls -1` will list a single entry per line

Note #2: If you don't want to transform the file names, you can omit the `xargs` stage (which allows you to do basic string manipulation via `-I{}`), and send directly to output file:

```sh
ls -1 *.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
man echo
...
-n     do not output the trailing newline
```

thanks karel,  I was being low effort.

```
tr '\n' ' '  list.txt
```

will put the words in the list together with spaces

Comment: Yyou still didn't get it right.